# The origin of ни пуха ни пера - к чёрту

Tags: этимология, идиомы

Why do we say `ни пуха ни пера` wishing someone good luck?

The traditional response is also interesting. People are expected to say `к чёрту`.

What is the origin of the idiom?

Comment: https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D1%83%D1%85%D0%B0_%D0%BD%D0%B8_%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0#%D0%AD%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%8F

Comment: Статьи в вики без ссылок, конечно, надёжный источник, но почему-то в корпусе русского языка первое упоминание "ни пуха ни пера" датировано 1917-1925 гг, следующие - 1925 годом и позже.

Comment: People are superstitious that explains ongoing popularity (and even if you are not, the phrase may be something that you are expected to say). The idiom is similar to "break a leg" in theatre.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

***Ни пуха ни пера*** – это значит "ни зверя вам, ни птицы".

Сначала это было напутствие для охотников, скрытое пожелание им удачи.

"Недобрые слова" должны были услышать лесные духи,  и тогда они уйдут и не будут мешать охоте (зачем повторяться, если дело уже сделано).

А ответ "к черту" – это переадресация сказанного: пусть черт это тоже услышит и, конечно же, сделает всё наоборот.

https://slovar.cc/rus/frazeologiya/1468037.html

https://www.proza.ru/2015/11/22/326